# SQLite - How to replace string operators and convert it into integer value?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a string column which has dots.How can I replace the dots with nothing`("")` ? After the replacing , I want to convert this string into integer value.

For example :

```
1.450.753 (String)
```

to

```
1450753  (Integer)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE CAST(replace(yourString,'.','') AS INTEGER) > otherValue
```

I think this is the answer.